# The memory usage is over the capacity error on scaling up Streaming Units

Tags: azure, azure-stream-analytics

Today I scaled up Streaming Units (from 3) to 18 on Azure Streaming Analytics job. And during that the following processing error happened:

> The memory usage is over the capacity for one or more of the query steps. Event processing may be delayed or stop making progress. This may be a result of large window in your query, large events in your input, large out of order tolerance window, or a combination of the above. Please try to partition your query, or break down your query to more steps, and add Streaming Unit resources from the Scale tab to avoid such condition.

It was probably caused by this part of my query

```sql
GroupedDailyTenantQuery AS (
SELECT 
    [TenantId],
    System.Timestamp() AS WindowEnd,
    [ItemType],
    COUNT(*) AS EventCount,
    COUNT(distinct(ExternalId)) AS ViewerCount

FROM
    ReaderQuery
 GROUP BY TumblingWindow(Duration(day, 1), Offset(hour, 5)), TenantId, [ItemType]
)
```

And the huge number of backlogged input events: ~5M

[image]

This error caused automatic restart and at that time we decided to stop and try with 6 SU, which ended up properly. However, I don't understand what 18 SU caused that issue, and 6 went well.

[image]

With 18 SU utilization was at 90% and more. And now I want to understand why it happened? And what I can do with my query to be able to run 18 SU.

I read [that](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-scale-jobs) and according to this I should be able to run max 6 SU without partitioning. However, a day before I made a test on even bigger set of items. And all went fine.